# How to set column width dynamicaly in dynamic jasper excel report?

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

I am developing excel report using [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) API. I am able to generate the report from the given datasource, but the columns in the report still appeared very narrow. I searched to get a solution for this, in many place people answer with `setUseFullPageWidth(true);` in `DynamicReportBuilder` . I tried this, but it does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use:
setWidth(Integer)

```
    AbstractColumn[] startColsParams = {
            ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(new ColumnProperty(KEY_AA_ID, String.class.getName()))
                .setWidth(new Integer(40)).setTitle("AA").setStyle(style).build(),
            ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(new ColumnProperty(KEY_BB_ID, String.class.getName()))
                .setWidth(new Integer(160)).setTitle("BB").setStyle(style).build(),             
    };
```